# ZF2 render form with data from database

Tags: zend-form, render, zend-framework2

I want to edit a record from a database with a Zend Form (Zend Framework 2).

In ZF1 I did in my controller:

```
$values = $table->getValues();
$form = new MyForm();
$form->populate($values);
$this->view->form = $form;
```

and in the viewscript:

```
<?php echo $this->form ?>
```

In ZF2 I tried in my controller:

```
$values = $table->getValues();
$form = new MyForm();
$form->populateValues($values); // form->setData($values) does not work either
return array('form' => $form);
```

and in my viewscript:

```
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form) ?>
<?php echo $this->formCollection($form) ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($form) ?>
```

but that renders the form, without data however.

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to `$form->prepare();` after `$form->setData($values);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `prepare()` on your form before you open it in your view script. For example:

```
<?php $form->prepare(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->openTag($form) ?>
<?php echo $this->formCollection($form) ?>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag($form) ?>
```

See the reference guide [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html)

Note the following point:

> the prepare() method. You must call it prior to rendering anything in
>   the view (this function is only meant to be called in views, not in
>   controllers).

Comment: As far as I can see prepare() only wraps the elements in the form name. My issue has been solved, see answer. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `$table->getValues()` in my code returns an arrayObject whereas `populateValues()` expects an array.